# Getting different results from different approaches in basic algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I want to get the value of $u$ from these two equations:

$$u\cos\phi=c\cos\phi+v_r
\\u\sin\phi=c\sin\phi \tag{1}$$

We assume that $\phi$ is not $0$ or a multiple of $\pi/2$. Also, $c>v_r>0$ and $u>0$.

One way is to re-write the equations as:
$$u\cos\phi-v_r=c\cos\phi
\\u\sin\phi=c\sin\phi \tag{2}$$

Squaring and adding gives us
$$u^2+v_r^2-2uv_r\cos\phi=c^2
\\\implies u^2+v_r^2\cos^2\phi-2uv_r\cos\phi=c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi$$
$$\implies u=v_r\cos\phi+\sqrt{c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi} \tag{3}$$

If we directly square and add the equations in $(1)$, we get
$$u^2=c^2+v_r^2+2cv_r\cos\phi \implies u=\sqrt{c^2+v_r^2+2cv_r\cos\phi} \tag{4}$$

Now I want to reconcile the two expressions for $u$ obtained in $(3)$ and $(4)$. So squaring their RHS and equating,

$$v_r^2\cos^2\phi+c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi+2v_r\cos\phi\sqrt{c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi} = c^2+v_r^2+2cv_r\cos\phi
\\\implies 2v_r\cos\phi\sqrt{c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi}=2v_r^2\sin^2\phi+2cv_r\cos\phi
\\\implies \cos\phi\sqrt{c^2-v_r^2\sin^2\phi}=v_r\sin^2\phi+c\cos\phi
\\\implies c^2\cos^2\phi-v_r^2\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi=v_r^2\sin^4\phi+c^2\cos^2\phi+2cv_r\sin^2\phi\cos\phi
\\\implies -v_r\cos^2\phi=v_r\sin^2\phi+2c\cos\phi
\\\implies -v_r=2c\cos\phi$$

Obviously I seem to have gone wrong somewhere, but I just cannot figure it out. Would be grateful for any help or error correction!

Comment: Wait a minute! Isn't $ u \sin \phi = c \sin \phi \Leftrightarrow u = c$???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sin\phi \neq 0$, we get $u = c$ and then $v_r = 0$. Since $v_r > 0$, we must have $\sin \phi = 0$, or $\phi = k\pi$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.
But you assume $\phi$ is neither $0$ nor a multiple of $\pi/2$, so your equations cannot be satisfied.